# How can I pull the most recent city/country from a specific Foursquare account?

Tags: api, geolocation, foursquare

I am trying to tie in a Foursquare account to a website, so it will return the country and city of a specific user's most recent checkin.  Foursquare offers private feeds for users, using private token URL's: https://foursquare.com/feeds/ but these feeds do not include the city and country.

Is there a way that I can pull this data from the feed, or is the best way to go through the Foursquare API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the feed together with [Google's GeoCoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#ReverseGeocoding).

From Foursquare, you get the coordinates of the last check-in(s). Then, you can use the coordinates and pass it to, e.g., Google's reverse GeoCoding API.

Sample Foursquare answer:

```
<item>
    <title>Geisenhausen</title>
    <description>@ Geisenhausen</description>
    ...
    <georss:point>48.46855070459905 12.259496372637319</georss:point>
</item>
```

Now, you can pass the coordinates to the Google API and get your city, country, etc.:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.46855070459905,12.259496372637319&sensor=false